# Self signed certificate in certificate chain only on local xampp but not on external server

Tags: php, apache, ssl, curl, xampp

I have installed both IIS and xampp (Apace) server on my Windows7. My issue is when I use the below code

```
`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlRequest);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);`
```

I tried everything on local xampp and iis but still getting the same error.

The things I tried on local server

- php.ini entry of curl.cainfo
- script entry of curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem');
- checking permissions on the folder

But if I put this code on godaddy servers with link to `cacert.pem` it works fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: "**still getting the same error.**" which is ?

Comment: yes  that is SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain and it only happens when i am behind a firewall in my company's network. if i try it outside the network it is fine. i am thinking that it is the company's certificate that is causing the issue. but do not know where to look for...